# How to create a default project under Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Related to this question: [Should "Library path" point to the source files of packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666292/should-library-path-point-to-the-source-files-of-packages)

Fabricio Araujo suggested that is not necessary to set the 'search path' for each new project by creating a 'Default Project Option'. How can this be done in Delphi XE7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How this can be done in Delphi XE7?

It cannot. This functionality was removed I'm not sure exactly when, but it has not been present for some considerable time.

What you can do is:

1. Create a new project.
2. Change its settings however you please.
3. Save this modified project template to some central location.
4. Whenever you make a new project, do so by copying this project template.

You can integrate this process into the IDE by saving your modified project template into the [Object Repository](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Object_Repository). Add a project to the repository with [Project | Add to Repository](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Add_to_Repository).

Comment: Hi David. I know that is not present anymore. But I hope that it could be altered/edited somehow. I mean Delphi has to load it from somewhere. Right?

Comment: Emba decided that the default project should not be something that users could mess with. Presumably because it caused lots of confusion. When users wondered why certain settings were strange and unusual values.

Comment: Embarcadero's great wisdom  :) :)

Comment: I actually think that they got this one right. I like that a new project has predictable state from one machine to the next. It's not like there aren't other ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: They could have put all the settings in one file so when you move the project to a different machine its state will be the same as in the old/original machine.

Comment: There are many things they could have done. Do you find yourself creating new projects that frequently? I know I don't. I also used shared option sets so that I can apply settings in multiple projects in a coordinated manner. I think that's much more powerful than each development machine having to be configured in a specific way.

Answer (score 3):

Prompted by your q, and more for amusement than anything else, I decided to try
writing an IDE-plugin that would provide a way to store some preferred project
settings somewhere and allow you to apply them to the current project.

To use, prepare and save a sample .Ini file containing your preferred settings in the format shown below (it's important to get the project option names right, see below for how to do find them out), then compile the unit below into a new package and install it in the IDE.  Its gui will pop up when you subsequently open a project.

The settings in the .Ini are loaded into a ValueList editor and pressing the
[Return] key in one of the values will apply it to the project.

Interestingly, the names the IDE uses for the Project seetings are the same in XE7
as they are in D7.  Iow, the XE7 IDE uses these internally rather than the names
which appear in the .DProj XML file.  You can get a full list of them by clicking the `GetOptions` button.

As usual when working with the IDE OTA services, the code has to include
a fair amount of "baggage".

Tested in D7 and XE7.

Sample Ini File:

```
[settings]
OutputDir=Somewhere
UnitOutputDir=Somewhere else
UnitDir=$(DELPHI)
ObjDir=$(DELPHI)
SrcDir=$(DELPHI)
ResDir=$(DELPHI)
```

Code:

```
unit ProjectOptionsXE7u;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, ToolsAPI, Grids, ValEdit, IniFiles;

type
  TProjectOptionsForm = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    ValueListEditor1: TValueListEditor;
    btnGetOptions: TButton;
    procedure btnGetOptionsClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ValueListEditor1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  private
    function GetCurrentProject: IOTAProject;
    procedure GetOptionsFromIni;
    procedure UpdateOptionValue;
  public
    Services: IOTAServices;
    ProjectGroup : IOTAProjectGroup;
    Project: IOTAProject;
    Options : IOTAProjectOptions;
    ModServices: IOTAModuleServices;
    Module: IOTAModule;
    NotifierIndex: Integer;
    Ini : TMemIniFile;
    IsSetUp : Boolean;
    SetUpCount : Integer;
    procedure GetProjectOptions;
    procedure SetUp;
  end;

var
  ProjectOptionsForm: TProjectOptionsForm;

procedure Register;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
  TIdeNotifier = class(TNotifierObject, IOTANotifier, IOTAIDENotifier)
  protected
    procedure AfterCompile(Succeeded: Boolean);
    procedure BeforeCompile(const Project: IOTAProject; var Cancel: Boolean);
    procedure FileNotification(NotifyCode: TOTAFileNotification;
      const FileName: string; var Cancel: Boolean);
  end;

procedure Register;
begin
  ProjectOptionsForm:= TProjectOptionsForm.Create(Nil);
  ProjectOptionsForm.Services := BorlandIDEServices as IOTAServices;
  ProjectOptionsForm.NotifierIndex := ProjectOptionsForm.Services.AddNotifier(TIdeNotifier.Create);
end;

procedure CloseDown;
begin
  ProjectOptionsForm.Services.RemoveNotifier(ProjectOptionsForm.NotifierIndex);
  ProjectOptionsForm.Close;
  ProjectOptionsForm.Free;
end;

procedure TIdeNotifier.AfterCompile(Succeeded: Boolean);
begin
end;

procedure TIdeNotifier.BeforeCompile(const Project: IOTAProject; var Cancel: Boolean);
begin
end;

procedure TIdeNotifier.FileNotification(NotifyCode: TOTAFileNotification;
  const FileName: string; var Cancel: Boolean);
begin
  if NotifyCode in [ofnProjectDesktopLoad, ofnActiveProjectChanged]  then begin
    ProjectOptionsForm.Show;
//    ProjectOptionsForm.Memo1.Lines.Add('Got notification');
    ProjectOptionsForm.SetUp;
//    ProjectOptionsForm.Memo1.Lines.Add('after GetProjectOptions');
  end;
end;

procedure TProjectOptionsForm.btnGetOptionsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  KeyName,
  Value,
  S : String;
  V : Variant;
  i : Integer;
begin
  GetProjectOptions;
  ValueListEditor1.Strings.Clear;
  for i := Low(Options.GetOptionNames) to High(Options.GetOptionNames) do begin
    try
      KeyName := Options.GetOptionNames[i].Name;
      if CompareText(KeyName, 'HeapSize') = 0 then
        NoOp;
      V := Options.Values[KeyName];
      if not VarIsEmpty(V) then
        Value := VarToStr(V)
      else
        Value := '';
      ValueListEditor1.InsertRow(KeyName, Value, True);
    except
      //  Reading some CPP-related settings cause exceptions
      S := '***Error   ' + KeyName; // + ': ' + IntToStr(Options.Values[KeyName].Kind);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TProjectOptionsForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Ini.Free;
end;

procedure TProjectOptionsForm.GetOptionsFromIni;
var
  i : Integer;
  KeyName : String;
  TL : TStringList;
begin
  ValueListEditor1.Strings.Clear;
  TL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Ini.ReadSection('Settings', TL);
    Assert(TL.Count > 0);
    for i := 0 to TL.Count - 1 do begin
      KeyName := TL[i];
      ValueListEditor1.InsertRow(KeyName, Ini.ReadString('Settings', KeyName, ''), True);
    end;
  finally
    TL.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TProjectOptionsForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  IniFileName : String;
begin
  IniFileName := 'd:\aaad7\ota\ProjectOptions.Ini'; //  <beware of hard-code path
  Ini := TMemIniFile.Create(IniFileName);
  GetOptionsFromIni;
end;

function TProjectOptionsForm.GetCurrentProject: IOTAProject;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := nil;
  ModServices := BorlandIDEServices as IOTAModuleServices;
  for i := 0 to ModServices.ModuleCount - 1 do
  begin
    Module := ModServices.Modules[i];
    if Supports(Module, IOTAProjectGroup, ProjectGroup) then begin
      Result := ProjectGroup.ActiveProject;
      Options := Result.ProjectOptions;
      Exit;
    end
    else if Supports(Module, IOTAProject, Project) then
    begin // In the case of unbound packages, return the 1st
      if Result = nil then begin
        Result := Project;
        Options := Result.ProjectOptions;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TProjectOptionsForm.GetProjectOptions;
begin
  Assert(Project <> Nil, 'Project');
  Options := Project.ProjectOptions;
end;

procedure TProjectOptionsForm.SetUp;
begin
  Project := GetCurrentProject;
  GetProjectOptions;
  Inc(SetUpCount);
  Caption := 'Setup done ' + IntToStr(SetUpCount);
  IsSetUp := True;
end;

procedure TProjectOptionsForm.UpdateOptionValue;
var
  Rect : TGridRect;
  S : String;
  KeyName,
  Value : String;
  Row,
  Col : Integer;
begin
  if Options = Nil then
    Exit;
  Rect := ValueListEditor1.Selection;
//  S := 'left: %d top: %d right: %d, bottom: %d';
//  S := Format(S, [Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom]);
//  Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
  Row := Rect.Bottom;
  Col := Rect.Left - 1;
  KeyName := ValueListEditor1.Cells[Col, Row];
  Value := ValueListEditor1.Values[KeyName];

  Options.SetOptionValue(KeyName, Value);
  Options.ModifiedState := True;

  Module.Save(False, False);
end;

procedure TProjectOptionsForm.ValueListEditor1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var
    Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = #13 then
    UpdateOptionValue;
end;

initialization

finalization
  CloseDown;
end.
```