# OK to use DCC_UsePackage in optset?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

When you start using a package in a project you always have to change the same settings in the project options - search path, used run-time packages, unit aliasses, probably more. I'm currently trying to "outsource" all these settings for a certain library into an option set (*.optset). For search path and unit aliasses I could easily configure that using the XE6 IDE. But I didn't find an entry for run-time packages. So I manually added the relevant line

```
<DCC_UsePackage>MyPackage;$(DCC_UsePackage)</DCC_UsePackage>
```

to the optset file in a text editor and it seems to work. But I'm worried because the IDE doesn't support this. Is there a hidden gotcha?

Comment: Should be fine. Not surprising if ide doesn't cater for all possible options.

Comment: @David: I did expect they just reuse the existing options dialog with some minor modifications. :-)

Comment: You might take a look at my answer to this q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215008/how-to-create-a-default-project-under-delphi-xe7/33289303#33289303.

Comment: @MartynA Options sets are much more powerful

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Yes, I realise that, but I remember you telling me a while back that they weren't applicable to something or other I was trying, though the details escape me right now.

Comment: @MartynA: Thanks, looks interesting. I'll try how the optset thing works out first. :-)